# TFS SSL Setup over the internet

Tags: tfs, windows-server-2008

I am new to TFS and have been having issues with setting it up to be accessible on the internet.

I have set up TFS 2008 with SSL(HTTPS) on ports 8081, 81, and 17013 etc... for the respective services, on a single server deployment, with basic authentication, with server exposed as a DMZ by my router.

How can I access the TFS server outside my home if the ports are blocked on the network I am on, like those WIFI hotspots or in my company's network.

Please advice.

Cheers.

Comment: @Titan, you might want to post this question to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  You'll need to use a port that isn't blocked.  443 should be a safe bet.  If all else fails, and you don't care about moving your default websites (sharepoint, report server, etc) to another port, use 80.

NOTE: make sure you follow the TFS specific directions on MSDN.  If you just start changing stuff in IIS Admin you will be very unhappy.